# Recording image name into the database in PHP

Tags: php, database, image, upload

I used this code to upload image(PHP);

```
if(in_array(strtolower($_FILES['img']['type']),$m)){ 
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'],"./$upload/{$_FILES['img']['name']}");
```

`$file=$_FILES['img']['name'];
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO database (img)
                           VALUES ('$file')", $con) or die(mysql_error());`

...

When I print `$_FILES['img']['name']` ,it gives the name of the image.However, when I try to send this image name to the database , it records always as a "image/png".

How can i fix it?

thanks

Comment: Show us that code that stores the filepath in the database. It sounds like you're storing the mimetype instead.

Comment: Then you need to show your DB code. Showing some file moving code is irrelevant when the problem is database related. Plus, this code is EXTRAODINARILY dangerous, and allows malicious users to scribble a file on your server ANYWHERE they want. Don't try this stuff until you've learned how to code securely in PHP.

Comment: Check your sql statement that you have the correct values for each of the fields.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**pink box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ). You also inject variables into your query making your entire database hackable. Look up SQL injection.